# The differences between "to make a stink" and "to make a fuss"

Tags: phrase-choice

Hi I think these idioms have similar meaning but is there any difference between them in terms of meaning, usage and strenght.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **stink** is always negative.  If you *make a fuss* in order to express your displeasure, you have *made a stink.*  The insurance company made a stink over the number of speeding tickets I had, and almost cancelled my policy.  I could say they "made a fuss" over the tickets too, but "a stink" conveys the unpleasantness of the matter.

On the other hand, I could make a big fuss over my wife's birthday by putting up decorations and inviting lots of her best friend's over for a party.  I ought to do that.  She would like it.

If I fail to make a **fuss** over her birthday, she might make a **stink** over how I ignored it.

If I said, without context, that *"she made a **fuss** over the puppy I bought as a surprise,* you don't know whether she was pleased or not.

Comment: *making a fuss* can also be used if you overdo something unnecessarily, that would otherwise be simple to do.

Comment: @Adam Thank you .What you wrote is very informative.